# HMR error when using webpack in IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, webpack, asp.net-core

I've got an ASP.NET Core 2 Angular app that's using webpack HMR. While it works on IIS Express, I get the following error in the browser console when running on local IIS server (as a virtual directory) in my dev environment:

`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

I found a post about this on GitHub and tried all of the things that the author has talked about: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1475

Anyone else who's having this issue and/or has resolved this?